# Placeholder for an Iframe php

Tags: iframe, text, input, placeholder

I use an onclick event on a text box. If a user clicks inside the textbox, a youtube video is loaded inside an iframe (in div "video_holder"). Next to this div, there is a div called "text_holder", which dynamically changes the text. The functionality works, but the problem is that I want to show an image instead of the iframe when the onclick event has not been invoked. Say a placeholder for the iframe when script is not invoked.

This is my code:

```
<script>
function changeCaption(vCaption){
var cap = document.getElementById('text_holder');
cap.innerHTML = vCaption;
}
</script>


input type="text" name="a" value="1" onclick="changeCaption('test123'); yt_video.location.href=link" >


<div id="video_holder"> 
    <iframe name="yt_video" id="yt_video">
    </iframe>                                     
</div>
<div id="text_holder">
     Some initial text.   
</div>
```

I hope someone can help with this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: simple set iframe src=your image path when your onclick event will invoked  then value will be change or simple <div id="video_holder"><image scr="your iamge path" /></div>

Comment: Thanks Nanhe, but it doesn't seem to work. When I put the image inside the div, the image is shown, but also the iframe is loaded under the image. So on teh onclick event the image remains above the iframe. When i use the src=image , the iframe loads with my site with a 404 page error (inside the iframe).

Comment: If I place the image in the text_holder, it works. The video_holder is not replaced. Only the location.href of the iframe is updated. So... how can I replace the video_holder from an initial image to the iframe? I think that is the problem.

Comment: can you put your complete code.

Comment: Well actually this is my relevant code. Only I simpified the input. My real input looks like:                        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $sizesArray[$i]['size']; ?>" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo $_SESSION[$sizesArray[$i]['size']];?>" onclick="changeCaption('<?php echo $sizesArray[$i]['size_description']; ?>'); yt_video.location.href='<?php echo $sizesArray[$i]['size_yt_link']; ?>'"> cm

Comment: I found it... src=<img src= ... by mistake... Thanks anyway Nanhe !